# VIsual flow in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow

I've embeded a visual flow onto a visualforce page and am having trouble getting the page to render with viewing the page publicly (when not logged it). The input fields aren't showing up. What do I need to do in order to change this? Are there resources that spell out that process?

Do I need a controller? Not really sure how controllers work and haven't found a resource that goes over embedding flows into a visualforce page in depth. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" language="en" standardStylesheets="false" >


    <head> 
        <!--<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>-->
        <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.towsonwrapper_css)}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>
<body class="gridlock third_party">
        <!-- Skip to Content Link -->

        <a href="#page" id="skip_to_content" class="offscreen">Skip to Main Content</a>

        <!-- Header -->

        <header class="header" id="header" role="banner">

            <section class="secondary">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="all-full">
                        <div class="mobile_logo_container">
                            <a href="" class="mobile_logo_wrapper">
                                <span class="mobile_logo"><img src="{!$Resource.TUMainLogo}"/></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="" class="back_link">Back to Towson.edu</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="primary">
                <div class="row">
                    <nav class="all-full primary_navigation">
                        <div class="primary_navigation_item">
                            <a href="" class="primary_navigation_link">Link One</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="primary_navigation_item">
                            <a href="" class="primary_navigation_link">Link Two</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="primary_navigation_item">
                            <a href="http://www.towson.edu" class="primary_navigation_link">Link Three</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="primary_navigation_item">
                            <a href="" class="primary_navigation_link">Link Four</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="primary_navigation_item">
                            <a href="" class="primary_navigation_link">Link Five</a>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="mobile">

                <div class="mobile_logo_container">
                    <a href="" class="mobile_logo_wrapper">
                        <span class="mobile_logo">Towson University
</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="mobile_navigation_container">
                    <a href="" class="mobile-half tablet-half desktop-half mobile_navigation_handle">
                        <span class="navigation_label">Navigation</span>
                        <span class="close_label">Close</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="mobile_navigation">

                        <nav class="mobile_primary_navigation">
                            <a href="" class="mobile_primary_navigation_link">Link One</a>
                            <a href="" class="mobile_primary_navigation_link">Link Two</a>
                            <a href="" class="mobile_primary_navigation_link">Link Three</a>
                            <a href="" class="mobile_primary_navigation_link">Link Four</a>
                            <a href="" class="mobile_primary_navigation_link">Link Five</a>
                        </nav>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </section>

        </header>

        <main class="page" id="page" role="main">

            <section class="page_content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="mobile-full tablet-full desktop-full max-10">

                        <!-- Begin WYSIWYG Area -->

                        <div class="wysiwyg">
                            <h1>Admission Decline Form</h1>
                            <h2>We're so sorry to see you go!</h2>
                            <!--<h3>h3 Frutiger LT Pro Bold Condensed, 24 pt 28 Leading</h3>
                            <h4>H4 FRUTIGER LT PRO BOLD CONDENSED, 18 PT, KERNING .6</h4>
                            <h5>H5 FRUTIGER LT PRO LIGHT, KERNING 1.75, UPPERCASE </h5>-->

                            <!--<figure class="image block_right">
                                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/288/food" alt=""></img>
                                <figcaption class="caption">Lorem ipsum unc aliquam sollicitudin urna, ut euismod urna fermentum sed. Etiam lacinia tristique justo, in aliquam dui facilisis nec. Etiam luctus nibh magna, ultrices facilisis lorem dapibus a. Vivamus venenatis rutrum lectus, a feugiat metus ultricies ut.
                            </figcaption>
                            </figure>-->

                            <p>We hate that you won't be joining us here at Towson but we understand it may not be 
                                    the right fit for you. Please take a moment and let us know why you decided not to attend.</p>
                        <span style="">
                            <flow:interview name="Admission_Decline_Reason" buttonLocation="bottom"/>
                        </span>


                        </div>

                        <!-- End: WYSIWYG Area -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

        </main>

        <footer class="footer short" id="footer" role="contentinfo">
            <div class="row">

                <section class="mobile-full tablet-half desktop-4">
                    <a href="" class="footer_logo_container">
                        <span class="footer_logo">Towson University</span>
                    </a>
                </section>

                <section class="mobile-full tablet-full desktop-8 short_container">
                    <div class="short_info">&copy;2016 8000 York Road
                        <span class="pad">|</span> Towson, MD 21252
                        <span class="pad">|</span>
                        <a href="tel:+14107042000" class="footer_phone_number">410-704-2000</a>
                    </div>
                </section>

            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- Compiled JS -->
        <script>
        var WWW_ROOT = "";
        </script>
        <script src="js/site.js"></script>

</body>

</apex:page>
```